# function to change rows to column of a dataset base on id column

Tags: r

Appended is part of my data set in R.

```
id time residuals
1   2   -2.0
1   3   2.1
2   2   -1.3
2   3   2
3   2   -1.4
3   3   1.5
```

I want to convert data set on the basis of id like this

```
id  time1 time2
1   -2.0   2.1
2   -1.3    2
3    -1.4   1.5
```

Is there any function available in R or should I code to transform data?!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `spread` after `mutate`ing the 'time' column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate(time = str_c("time", time -1)) %>%
    spread(time, residuals)
#     id time1 time2
#1  1  -2.0   2.1
#2  2  -1.3   2.0
#3  3  -1.4   1.5
```

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), time = c(2L, 3L, 
 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), residuals = c(-2, 2.1, -1.3, 2, -1.4, 1.5)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -6L))
```